# Show the existence and Calcualte the $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_{[0,1]}(1-e^{\frac{-x^2}{n}})dλ(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, convergence-divergence, definite-integrals

I wanted to know if I am right with this problem.

I have to determine whether the limit for $n \rightarrow \infty$ exists and, if so, I have to calculate it.

The Integral is:

$I_n=\int_{[0,1]}(1-e^{\frac{-x^2}{n}})dλ(x)$

First, to show the existence of the limit, we can use the theorem about the dominated convergence.
Since $f_n:=1-e^{\frac{-x^2}{n}}$ is measurable, converges pointwise to 0, and $|f_n|\leq g(x):=1$ we can prove the existence of the limit.

For calculating the limit I wanted to use the theorem of Beppo Levi.

The functions f_n are measurable and nonnegative in [0,1] and $I_1=\int_{[0,1]}(1-e^{\frac{-x^2}{1}})dλ(x) < \infty$.

The functions are μ-decreasing monotonically almost everywhere against a measurable function (null function).
So $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\int_{[0,1]}(1-e^{\frac{-x^2}{n}})dλ(x)=\int_{[0,1]}\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}(1-e^{\frac{-x^2}{n}})dλ(x)=0$

Am I right? Need I to use Beppo Levi to solve it, or the first theorem was enough to use the $\lim$ under the integral?

Comment: Dominated convergence also tells you that $\lim_n\int f_n=\int f$. So you don't have to use Beppo Levi.

Comment: Thanks for the information